tkz-euclide: tangent to a circle and point of tangency
I would appreciate clarification on how to find the tangent to a circle and get the coordinates of the tangency point using tkz-euclide library. Given a point A and a circle of center O, find the tangents and point of tangency.

The code below approximates one of the tangents by trial and error. I am looking for a way to automate this. I made several attempts with \tkzTangent[from=A] and \tkzTangent[at=A], but the part with \tkzGetPoints{s}{t} seems to fail (see for instance page 75 of the manual 5.05c). I would appreciate an answer that would detail several approaches within the tkz-euclide paradigm.
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3]

  % some points
  \tkzDefPoint(0,0){A}
  \tkzDefPoint(1,0){B} 

  % draw line connecting A and B
  %\tkzDrawLines(A,B)

  % label the points
  \tkzDrawPoint[color=black](A)
  \tkzLabelPoints[below left](A)
  %\tkzLabelPoints[below right](B)

  % center of circle
  \tkzDefPoint(2,1){O} 

  % label center of circle
  \tkzDrawPoint[color=blue](O)
  \tkzLabelPoints[above right](O)

  % draw circle at center O and through point B
  \tkzDrawCircle[color=blue](O,B)

  % find the point of tangency through A to the circle
  % FAKE IT
  \tkzDefPoint(0.72,1.61){T} 
  \tkzDrawLines[color=red](A,T)
  \tkzDrawLines[color=blue](O,T)

  % calculate it
  %\tkzTangent[from=A](O,B)\tkzGetPoints{s}{t}
  %\tkzDrawLines[color=orange](A,t)

  % mark the right angle | isn't there an alpha option?
  % \tkzMarkRightAngle[size=0.1,fill=red!30!white,draw=none](O,T,A)

  % mark the right angle | too many black contours...
  \tkzMarkRightAngle[size=0.1](O,T,A)

  % label the tangency point
  \tkzDrawPoint[color=red](T)
  \tkzLabelPoints[above left](T)

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I haven't been able to find guidance on this on stackexchange. There are related questions, but they do not provide an explicit answer to my question, e.g.
How can I get a tangent to a circle in a point with tkz-euclide?
Assuming a line is tangent to a circle in tkz-euclide
How to properly draw a circle with two tangent line marking the right angles

tkzTangent is no longer a macro in tkz-euclide. You need to use :
\tkzDefLine[tangent from = A](O,B)

